# Error al hacer un CRUD en .NET con MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework-6

Estoy realizando un CRUD en .Net y ya realicé el insert pero al momento de hacer delete y update me aparece el siguiente error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'El valor no puede ser nulo.
> Nombre del parámetro: entity'

Esto tengo en mi controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Eliminar(String Cedula)
    {
        
        using (proyectoEntities db = new proyectoEntities())
        {
            
             var oTabla = db.Usuario.Find(Cedula);
            db.Usuario.Remove(oTabla);
            db.SaveChanges();
           

        }
         return Redirect("~/Usuario/");
    }
```

Esto tengo en mi view:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger"href="~/Usuario/Eliminar/@oElemento.Cedula"> Eliminar</a>
```

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Repetir las preguntas no esta bien visto. Por favor, cuando tengas actualizaciones a tu pregunta, hacelas sobre las mismas

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error al hacer un CRUD en .NET](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/383873/error-al-hacer-un-crud-en-net)

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente el parámetro `Cedula` del método sea `null` ya que no esta incluido en la ruta, intenta cambiar el nombre a `id` o en el `href` colocar la ruta de la siguiente forma `~/Usuario/Eliminar?Cedula=@oElemento.Cedula`.

Answer (score 0):

Llega nulo porque el elemento no está siendo definido en el route config:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", //Aquí le estás diciendo que vas a recibir "id"
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

En este caso, tendrías que cambiar `Cedula` por `id` y tendrías el valor enviado correctamente.

Una alternativa:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Eliminar/{Cedula:string}")] //Aqui defines la ruta para el action del controlador que estás trabajando.
public ActionResult Eliminar(String Cedula)
{
    
    using (proyectoEntities db = new proyectoEntities())
    {
        
         var oTabla = db.Usuario.Find(Cedula);
        db.Usuario.Remove(oTabla);
        db.SaveChanges();
       

    }
     return Redirect("~/Usuario/");
}
```

Comment: Si pone ?cedula=@oElemento.Cedula en el url no depende de la tabla de ruteo.